# Rename filename with truncated folder names

Tags: string, vbscript, scripting, file-rename

I am currently writing a script which renames file names by using the complete path of the file as prefix for the file name. This works well with `GetAbsolutePathName` from `FileSystemObject`. I deleted the prompt by using the `Right()` function and `Replace()` to substitute the backslash with a `-`.

So far everything works well. However, to avoid too long filenames due to long paths and many subfolders I wold like to truncate every foldername in the filename-string after 4 characters. I just wonder what would be the most elegant way.

Identifying the position of all `-` saving them in an array and making a loop which calculates the position where to truncate seems to be a bit complicated and would be probably slow I guess. Does anybody know have a more elegant idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: I consider the question sufficiently clear, even without code. The OP described what he's trying to achieve, and the way he considers going about it, then asked if there's a better way than what he's thinking of.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. As Ansgar said I was curious about some other ideas but will try to elaborate a bit more on the question next time.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do what you want is to [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5%28v=vs.84%29) the original path at backslashes, truncate each element to 4 characters tops with the [`Left`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk3xcs8k%28v=vs.84%29) function, then [`Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yscc53h0%28v=vs.84%29) the modified array back to a string.

```
path = "Users\someuser\Documents"

arr = Split(path, "\")
For i=0 To UBound(arr)
  arr(i) = Left(arr(i), 4)
Next
prefix = Join(arr, "-")   'result: "User-some-Docu"
```

Beware that the `FileSystemObject` accepts both `\` and `/` as path separator, so it may ba a good idea to canonicalize `/` to `\` first.

Comment: Thanks, Ansgar, this is a quite elegant way. I will try how it works with a large amount of files. Probably, I will try recursion over the folder structure.  Cheers,